# Declaring an array with size std::streamoff

Tags: c++

I have this line to get file size

```
std::streamoff _responseLength = _responseIn.tellg();
```

I am allocating memory for a wchar_t pointer with,

```
wchar_t* _responseString = new wchar_t[_responseLength];
```

I get a warning about `'initializing' : conversion from 'std::streamoff' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data`.

What should I do to completely eliminate the warning by the compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

std::streamoff is a large (at least 64 bits) **signed** integer (often `long long` or `int64_t`, or `long` if that is 64 bits). The type used to express the size of objects and the length of arrays and containers is `size_t`, which is unsigned, often `unsigned long`. You need to `static_cast` your streamoff value to a size_t.

Note that `tellg()` may return -1. `static_cast`ing -1 to `size_t` will result in a huge positive value; trying to allocate that much memory will cause your program to fail. You need to explicitly check for -1 before casting.

Please do not use naked pointers and `new`. If you need a buffer, use the following:

```
std::vector<wchar_t> buffer(static_cast<size_t>(responseLength));
// use &buffer.front() if you need a pointer to the beginning of the buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

The new operator to allocate memory takes an `unsigned int` so the `std::streamoff` gets converted to an `unsigned int` to fit the requirement.

The limitation you get with this is that you cannot read a file bigger than 4GB.

To avoid this limitation, you need to read the file in pieces that fit into memory.

If your file is only about 100MB big, just ignore the warning.